# Angular how to block script on localhost and run on production?

Tags: angular

Disable running scripts from the index.html file on the localhost environment, on the production environment the script is to be run.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular Homework Task</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Start script -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(w,d,s,a,b) {
      a=d.createElement(s),a.innerHTML="alert('Attention production!')",b=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);
    })(window,document,'script');</script>
  <!-- End script-->
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put scripts like that in angular.

So put the in your app component and use this

```js
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
    if(environment.production) { /* ... */ }
    else { /* ... */ }
  }

}
```